# How to I prevent user from typing the same tag in the Textext textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tags, jquery-textext

I am using [Textext](http://textextjs.com/]) plugin for the tags. What am trying to achieve is to prevent multiple duplicates of the items(tags) typed in the textarea.

[image]

As you can see in the above pic the tag "C" is typed twice. It want to prevent the user from typing the duplicates. How do I do this?

I came across the [filter plugin](http://textextjs.com/manual/plugins/filter.html#textextfilter-isvalueallowed-value) But its functionality is little different from what I want.

I am sure there is some good way to achieve this. Please help!

Comment: can you create a demo for us on http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Just save somewhere the values that the user types in, and then for every new one, you can check if they already exist or not. ( be careful to also delete a value when the user deletes a tag )

Comment: I think the tags are being generated when user presses `space/enter` button. If so, store those tags in a array in `space/enter` key function and compare them with new values later.

Comment: Am not sure how the plugin handles the add functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to get the inside text:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('textarea');
var insideText = $(txt).parent().children('div').text();
```

The text will be in concatenated form. So, you need to take care when the user deletes the tag or creates a new tag.

To test the above code, run it in console tab of developer tool of the browser.

Comment: I found another way to solve my above problem. There is a "isTagAllowed" trigger, in which am checking if the tag to be inserted is already present in the global array of previously entered tags. If there is a tag already in that name, return false, else return true.